# Design Mode data not showing up with MVVM-Light

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

I created a UWP app using TemplateStudio with MVVM-Light and can't get design data to show up in Visual Studio (or Blend).

View Model Locator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    NavigationServiceEx _navigationService = new NavigationServiceEx();

    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if(ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IFooProvider, DesignFooProvider>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IFooProvider, FooProvider>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => _navigationService);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ShellViewModel>();
        Register<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
        Register<FooViewModel, FooView>();

        _navigationService.SetMainViewModel(MainViewModel);
    }

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();

    public ShellViewModel ShellViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ShellViewModel>();

    public FooViewModel FooViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<FooViewModel>();

    public void Register<VM, V>() where VM : class
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<VM>();
        _navigationService.Configure(typeof(VM).FullName, typeof(V));
    }
}
```

FooViewModel has an ObservableCollection that is bound to in FooView.xaml

Now when I run the actual code everything runs fine and my FooViewModel correctly gets populated with data from FooProvider.

Looking at FooView though in Visual Studio or Blend, no data is displayed in the ListBox of FooView.xaml.

Is there a way to debug what's going wrong during design time? How do I fix my locator to correctly display data in FooView during design time?

(Note: The only code I added to the above class was related to FooView related items, the others were prepopulated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to debug what's going wrong during design time?

Yep we can. Here are steps:

1. Open your **Task manager**, find out **XDesProc.exe** and log its PID from details tap
2. Set breakpoint to the constructor code or any code that you want to check
3. Open your app from Blend, find out the second **XDesProc.exe** and log its PID
4. Close FooView page.
5. Go to Visual Studio, choose Debug->Attach to Process, then choose managed(v4.6,v4.5,v4.0) code and then select the Blend PID of XDesProc.exe
6. Go back to Blend and open the page that you want to see design data issue
7. Visual Studio will breaks at the breakpoint you want.

By the way, I do not have your code so I'm not so sure whether I've reproduced your issue. You can debug an share us info after debugging.

> How do I fix my locator to correctly display data in FooView during design time?

A workaround here is to manually add the designtime data using the following way:

```
<Page
x:Class="MVVMLightStartUp.Views.FooViewPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vm="using:MVVMLightStartUp.ViewModels"
DataContext="{Binding FooViewViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:DesignTimeViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

And in code behind define a DesignTimeViewModel.cs:

```
 public class DesignTimeViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> BindingData { get; set; }

    public DesignTimeViewModel(DesignTimeDataService dataservice)
    {
        var FooList = dataservice.GetFoo();
        BindingData = new ObservableCollection<Foo>(FooList);
    }
}
```

For details you can refer to some of the following blogs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/displaying-data-in-the-designer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx

Comment: Debugging worked perfectly. The issue was this line:
`SimpleIoc.Default.Register(() => _navigationService);`
which threw an exception saying NavigationService was already registered. So I threw it in a design mode check and everything works now

Comment: OK. I can reproduce the same while using MVVMLight in my code. Sounds like this is a problem about MVVMLight